# Recordset is not applicable for the arguments (String[]) -- error when accepting multiple parameters

Tags: java, excel

I have tried to use excel as database for which I used the fillo dependency.
I have tried with a single parameter which is working fine. But when I try with multiple arguments it pops the following error :

> " The method getField(String) in the type Recordset is not applicable
>   for the arguments (String[])", error is on "multi_data".

Here is the code:

```
public static void read_by_excel(String query, String field, String ... multi_data) throws FilloException
        {

            ArrayList<Object> excel_data = new ArrayList<Object>();
            Fillo fillo = new Fillo();
            Connection connection = fillo.getConnection("C:\\Users\\Vishrut\\Desktop\\read_openxl.xlsx");
            String strQuery = query;
            Recordset rs = connection.executeQuery(strQuery);

            while (rs.next())
            {
                excel_data.add(rs.getField(field)+rs.getField(multi_data));     

            }

            for (Object data: excel_data)
            {
                System.out.println(data);
            }
            rs.close();
            connection.close();
            }
```

Here how it is called. It can take multiple parameters after "department".

```
    function_class.read_by_excel("select * from Sheet1 where employee_id = 60546", "department","salary");
```

Comment: can you plese add some row from **read_openxl.xlsx**?

Comment: employee_id salary department
60546 50000 IT
60579 40000 ECE
61171 80000 MCH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error message is clear, `getField(String)` method does not support being passed an array.

From your code, the multi_data parameter is an array

```
String ... multi_data
```

then you pass it to the getField method

```
rs.getField(multi_data)
```

Here is how I would do it : change the method signature

```
public static void read_by_excel(Integer emplyoee_id, String ...fields){
//...
}
```

Then replace

```
rs.getField(field) + rs.getField(multi_data)
```

by

```
Stream.of(fields).map(f -> rs.getField(f)).collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Note that I am assuming that `getField` returns a `String` (no public API doc for fillo so could not verify). Note sure you really want to do `rs.getField(field) + rs.getField(multi_data)` without a separator between the values. Consider using `joining(",")` or anything else.

Comment: yeah! i get that, is there any work around? i want dynamic result from excel just by passing field names as parameter.